# Comparison of the string with the data in the database

Tags: python, django, database

I would like to compare a sentence which I input to my code with any value in database.

There is my function which apply data into database from my page:

```
def create_author(request):
    form_author = AuthorForm()
    context = {'form_author': form_author}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_author = AuthorForm(request.POST)

    if form_author.is_valid():
        name = request.POST.get('name',)
        surname = request.POST.get('surname')
        if name == Author.name and surname == Author.surname:
            print("We have this author in database")
            # There should be stop.
        else:
            author_object = Author(name=name, surname=surname)
            author_object.save()

    return render(request, 'authors/create_author.html', context)
```

and it works but it only adds - doesn't check if any author exist in db.
Any ideas for fixing it? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists()`.
Instead of this

```
if name == Author.name and surname == Author.surname:
   print("We have this author in database")
```

**Try this**

```
if Author.objects.filter(name=name, surname=surname).exists():
   print("We have this author in database")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`get_or_create`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) here, like:

```
def create_author(request):
    form_author = AuthorForm()
    context = {'form_author': form_author}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_author = AuthorForm(request.POST)

    if form_author.is_valid():
        name = form_author.cleaned_data['name']
        surname = form_author.cleaned_data['surname']

        __, created = Author.objects.get_or_create(name=name, surname=surname)
        if not created:
            print("We have this author in database")
            # There should be stop.
    return render(request, 'authors/create_author.html', context)
```

We here will thus create an `Author` object, with the given `name` and `surname`, given such author does not yet exists. If it already exists, we retrieve it, but that is not that much of a problem.

Note that in case the POST is successful, you better use a redirect here, this is the [*Post/Redirect/Get* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) architectural pattern.

You also better use the `cleaned_data` of your `form_author`, instead of using the `request.POST` data directly, since that is cleaned. Finally in case `AuthorForm` is a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), you better let [**`.save()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) do the required work.